# Visualization with Pipeline Aggregation in Kibana and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, data-visualization, kibana, aggregation

I've been struggling around with some visualization in Kibana.

For this example I will be using data from kibana samples (kibana_sample_data_ecommerce).

So want I would like to do is a visualization that shows: how many customers did 1 order, how many customers did 2 orders, how many customers did 3 orders, and so on.

An example of visualization would be this:
[image]

Using a table visualization and aggregating for `Terms` in descending order I can get something like this: [image]

On the left of the table we have the customer's name and on the right the count of orders the customer did.

I don't know what kind of aggregation should I use now so I can group the customers with same values into a new label. Something like, from this
[image]

to this

[image]

Btw I'm using kibana 7.2

Any suggestions and ideas are welcome. 
Thank you!

Edit:

I want to be able to group customers with same results (nº of orders) under a new bucket (and if is possible with a custom label).

Comment: What kind of `aggretation` did you try? Provide that information in the question.

Comment: I'm using a Table visualization and I'm aggregating by `Terms` for field  `customer_full_name.keyword` and in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

Go for `Terms` aggregation on `order` field while setting the `Metric Aggregation` as `count`.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: There is no `order` field, I'm aggregating by Terms for `customer_full_name.keyword` field. Now with that result I would like to make another aggregation so I can group the customers with same amount of orders under a new bucket